# Is the complexity of the first code O(n), and the second code O(n ^2)?

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory

#### First code:

```
def Maximum__profit_more_efficient(list):
    """compute the maximum_profit of specific stock"""

    selling_date = 0
    buying_date =  0        

    for i in range(len(list)):            
        if list[i] > list[selling_date]:
            selling_date = i                                

    for j in range(len(list)):            
        if list[j] < list[buying_date] and j <= selling_date:                
            buying_date = j            
        elif  j > selling_date:
            break           

    print(list[selling_date] -  list[buying_date])
```

---

#### Second code:

```
def brute_force(list):  
    """compute the maximum_profit of specific stock, but with higher complexity"""

    selling_date = 0
    buying_date =  0

    i = 0
    j = 0
    exit = False

    while exit == False:
        if list[i] > list[selling_date]:
            selling_date = i            

        if  i < len(list):
            i = i + 1                

        if i == len(list):                
            while j < len(list):
                if list[j] < list[buying_date] and j <= selling_date:
                    buying_date = j                    
                j = j + 1
                if j == len(list):
                    exit = True

    print(list[selling_date] -  list[buying_date])
```

Comment: What is your reasoning about that question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of the first code is O(n) as you have guessed.
But the complexity of the second code is also O(n). Even though there is a nested loop in the second code, since the value of j is set to 0 just once outside the loops the time complexity is O(n) only.

Comment: Another way to see it: the loop on `j` will only run once before the loop on `i` exits, `if i == len(list):`.